# Pandas data frame compare and replace values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have two pandas data frames like below. The column 'No' is a common field. Based on 'No', i want to replace values in first data frame column 'Total'.

**Condition is** : Where ever 'No' matches, get 'Marks1' value from dataframe2 and replace in 'Total' column. If 'Marks1' is NULL, then get 'Marks2' value and replace in 'Total'. If both (Marks1/Marks2) are null, replace with null in the 'Total' column. 
The final result should be in data frame1. Both data frames has few hundred thousand records.

```
Data frame1
No|Total
1234|11
2515|21
3412|32
4854|
7732|53

Data frame2
No|Marks1|Marks2
1234|99|23
2515|98|31
3412||20
4854||98
7732||

Result :
No|Total
1234|99
2515|98
3412|20
4854|98
7732|
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) with replace missing values `Marks1` by `Marks2` with [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
df = df2.set_index('No')

df1['Total'] = df1['No'].map(df['Marks1'].fillna(df['Marks2']))
print (df1)
     No  Total
0  1234   99.0
1  2515   98.0
2  3412   20.0
3  4854   98.0
4  7732    NaN
```

If possible duplicated values in `No` for `df2` then use:

```
print (df2)
     No  Marks1  Marks2
0  1234    99.0    23.0 <- duplicated No
1  1234    98.0    31.0 <- duplicated No
2  3412     NaN    20.0
3  4854     NaN    98.0
4  7732     NaN     NaN

#newer pandas versions
df = df2.set_index('No').sum(level=0, min_count=1)
#oldier pandas versions
#df = df2.set_index('No').sum(level=0)
print (df)
      Marks1  Marks2
No                  
1234   197.0    54.0<- unique No, values are summed per index created by No
3412     NaN    20.0
4854     NaN    98.0
7732     NaN     NaN

df1['Total'] = df1['No'].map(df['Marks1'].fillna(df['Marks2']))
print (df1)
     No  Total
0  1234  197.0
1  2515    NaN
2  3412   20.0
3  4854   98.0
4  7732    NaN
```

If there is same index values in `df1` and `df2` and each `No` values matched use:

```
df1['Total'] = df2['Marks1'].fillna(df2['Marks2'])
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215751/discussion-on-answer-by-jezrael-pandas-data-frame-compare-and-replace-values).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`np.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) here.

```
m = df2['Marks1'].notna()
m1 = df2['Marks1'].isna() & df2['Marks2'].notna()
condlist = [m,m1]
choice = [df2['Marks1'] , df2['Marks2']]
df1['Total'] = np.select(condlist,choice,np.nan)

     No  Total
0  1234   99.0
1  2515   98.0
2  3412   20.0
3  4854   98.0
4  7732    NaN
```

Comment: I think you forgot to include `condlist` and `chioce`

Comment: Hi, i'm getting the error :          AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'notna'

Comment: @RK. You need to upgrade your pandas version. `.notna`, `isna`, `notnull` all have been added from `pandas 0.21.0`

Comment: i upgraded to pandas 0.22 and trying. When np.select encounters throwing below error :             raise ValueError('Length of values does not match length of ' 'index')
ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index